# Java compiled with Jar file(external library) and run but gets the error no main class in terminal

Tags: java, jdbc, terminal, compiler-errors, jar

I'm working on my project using drivers.

I compiled this command my java file on the terminal:

```
javac -cp drivers\mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:drivers\ojdbc11.jar Main.java
```

ran the Main.class file with:

```
java -cp drivers\mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:drivers\ojdbc11.jar Main
```

But it gives the error like:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

When I run the Main.class without the .jar files like:

```
java Main
```

it gives:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://<databaseURL>
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:708)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:230)
        at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

My code(Main.java) work on the Visual Studio Code.
The directions on the commands are totally right, and Main is not in any package.
What is the problem?

I tried what I could found on the internet
such as

```
java -cp .:drivers/mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:drivers/ojdbc11.jar Main
java -cp "drivers\mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:drivers\ojdbc11.jar" Main
```

Comment: The problem is the -cp argument.  You >do< have to have "." on the path.  You >don't< have to have to include "ojdbc11.jar" ... unless you are trying to talk to an Oracle DB.   Also ... if you are running on Windows, the classpath separator is ";" not ":".

Comment: Hint: rather than looking for random solutions on the internet, find and read the manual entries for the `java` and `javac` command *for your Java & OS platform* and read them, paying close attention to the sections that talk about how to specify the classpath.   If you read (re-read) the documentation, that will increase the probability you will get it right ... and not have to ask this question again for a different problem.